# jq select object whose key value in the list

Tags: json, jq

I have one script `./getClasses.sh` which returns comma separated list like `ApexClass1,ApexClass2`. There are more than two items in this list.

I want to use that list in `jq` to filter out JSON values by a certain key value, which coincides with one value from the list

I tried `in` operator

```
echo $(cat tests.json) | jq '.result.coverage.coverage[] | select(.name included($(./getClasses.sh)))'
```

and `includes` operator

```
echo $(cat tests.json) | jq '.result.coverage.coverage[] | select(.name in($(./getClasses.sh)))'
```

but both of them are failing with en error

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected IDENT, expecting ';' or ')' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
```

File `tests.json` contains a following JSON

```
{"status": 0,
  "result": {
    "summary": {
      "outcome": "Passed",
      "testsRan": 13,
      "passing": 13,
      "failing": 0,
      "skipped": 0,
      "passRate": "100%",
      "failRate": "0%"}, "tests": [], "coverage": {
      "coverage": [
        {
          "name": "ApexClass1",
          "totalLines": 25,
          "lines": {},
          "totalCovered": 23,
          "coveredPercent": 92}, {
          "name": "ApexClass2",
          "totalLines": 25,
          "lines": {},
          "totalCovered": 23,
          "coveredPercent": 92}, {
          "name": "ApexClass3",
          "totalLines": 25,
          "lines": {},
          "totalCovered": 23,
          "coveredPercent": 92}
      ],
      "records": []
    } } }
```

How can I achieve the desired output?

Comment: Your `tests.json` is invalid.

Comment: thanks, missed one closing brace, fixed that

Answer (score 2):

I think I got it.

I need to pass the strings as argument and then split it by comma and unbracket them like this:

```
classes=$(./getClasses.sh)
echo $(cat tests.json) | jq --arg classes $classes '.result.coverage.coverage[] | select(.name == ($classes | split(",")[])) | .totalLines' | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option using `inside()` <sup>[[docs](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#example52)]</sup> to check if `.name` exist in an array.

The array is build using: `"ApexClass1,AapexClass2" | split(",")` <sup>[[docs](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#example60)]</sup>

---

```
jq '[ .result.coverage.coverage[] | select([ .name ] | inside("ApexClass1,AapexClass2" | split(",") ) ) | . ]' tests.json
```

```json
[
  {
    "name": "ApexClass1",
    "totalLines": 25,
    "lines": {},
    "totalCovered": 23,
    "coveredPercent": 92
  },
  {
    "name": "ApexClass2",
    "totalLines": 25,
    "lines": {},
    "totalCovered": 23,
    "coveredPercent": 92
  }
]
```

---

###### [Online JqPlay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/0_xLXGefhd)

---

Local demo:

```
➜  find="ApexClass1,ApexClass3"
➜ 
➜  jq --arg find $find '[ .result.coverage.coverage[] | select([ .name ] | inside($find | split(",") ) ) | . ]' tests.json
[
  {
    "name": "ApexClass1",
    "totalLines": 25,
    "lines": {},
    "totalCovered": 23,
    "coveredPercent": 92
  },
  {
    "name": "ApexClass3",
    "totalLines": 25,
    "lines": {},
    "totalCovered": 23,
    "coveredPercent": 92
  }
]
➜
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it already

Comment: Yea I know, but my guess is that this solution could be a bit faster. Thought I'd share it anyway ;0

Comment: is `inside` faster than '='? If so, could you please explain?

Comment: This doesn't quite work based on my use case... A value of "n1" performing a check with`inside ("n2 n3 n11") | split(" ")` comes back as true, matching the "n1" against the "n11"...